# reactpixi Error: Could not initialize shader

Tags: reactjs, pixi.js

I have this very very simple application:

```
<Stage options={{backgroundColor: 0xffffff, radius: 1, forceCanvas: true}}>

    <Sprite image="baseBike.png" x={100} y={100}/>

    <Sprite image={this.state.saddle.image} x={this.state.saddle.x} y={this.state.saddle.y}
            scale={{x: this.state.saddle.scale.x, y: this.state.saddle.scale.y}}/>


    <Sprite image={this.state.steering.image} x={this.state.steering.x}
            y={this.state.steering.y}
            scale={{x: this.state.steering.scale.x, y: this.state.steering.scale.y}}/>
    <Sprite image="circle.png" x={290} y={90} scale={{x: 1, y: 1}}
            interactive={true}
            pointerdown={() => {
                this.toogleMenu("saddle");
            }}
    />
    <Sprite image="circle.png" x={530} y={130} scale={{x: 1, y: 1}}
            interactive={true}
            pointerdown={() => {
                this.toogleMenu("steering");
            }}
    />

</Stage>
```

As you might be able to see i am using the plugin [reactpixi](https://reactpixi.org/) now when my users go to the build site they get the following error:

```
Pixi.js Error: Could not initialize shader. compileProgram.js:35:16
gl.VALIDATE_STATUS false compileProgram.js:36:16
gl.getError() 0 compileProgram.js:37:16
Pixi.js Warning: gl.getProgramInfoLog() Programs with more than 16 samplers are disallowed on Mesa drivers to avoid crashing. compileProgram.js:42:20
TypeError: "Argument 1 of WebGL2RenderingContext.getProgramParameter is not an object."
```

as you can see from the code above ive tried to "force" it to canvas however without any success.

So does anyone know how i might fix this issue?

Comment: is this to a specific browser, or in all browsers.

Comment: @AkhilAravind it happens for my users in firefox

Comment: I have the same issue in firefox

Comment: This https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/issues/4478#issuecomment-346641933 worked for me